# Need to sort column by string and priority

Tags: google-sheets

I am currently pulling a list from a table using a query to search for "Book" and the results I'm getting are below but I need to sort a list based on preference that needs to span multiple columns.

```
=QUERY(A2:F6, "select A, B, C, D, E, F where B='Book' or C='Book' or D='Book' or E='Book' or F='Book' ")
```

I have tried Order by but seems to only be available for alphabetical and cant define a string

So I have:

```
Name    1st     2nd         3rd           4th           5th
Bill    Book            
Ted                                                     Book    
Joe                         Book                
Larry   Book         
Lisa                                      Book
```

and it needs to look like this

```
Name    1st     2nd         3rd             4th         5th
Bill    Book            
Larry   Book    
Joe                         Book                
Lisa                                        Book         
Ted                                                     Book
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the **`SORT` function outside the query** and sort ascending by the 1st column:

```
=SORT(QUERY(A2:F6, "select A, B, C, D, E, F where B='Book' or C='Book' or D='Book' or E='Book' or F='Book' "),1,1)
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [`SORT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150)

Comment: This method sorts column A alphabetically. You can test it by changing "Brian" to "Larry" for example

Comment: _"This method sorts column A alphabetically"_. Yes it does. That is what your expected results - _"and it needs to look like this"_- seem to ask for. Sorry if I misunderstood. Please share a sheet with data  and scenario with expected results.

Answer (score 0):

We just have to add an ORDER BY clause to the query for the 2nd to 6th column,  and the ordering should be in the descending order. The following query will give you the desired output:

```
=QUERY(A2:F6, "select A, B, C, D, E, F where B='Book' or C='Book' or D='Book' or E='Book' or F='Book' ORDER BY B desc,C desc,D desc,E desc,F desc")
```

The output will look as follows:

```
Name    1st     2nd         3rd             4th         5th
Bill    Book            
Brian   Book    
Joe                         Book                
Lisa                                        Book         
Ted                                                     Book
```

Comment: The problem there is if B3 contains "Apple" it will not work as Order by is sorting alphabetically

Comment: @Oracle Is it not feasible to remove the fields other than 'book' if you only want to see the book preferences?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo - I could work with that as long as the names are in descending order of priority